# Writing Python iteration to JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have the following code below, that iterates through months to create an API link, my goal is to  export this to a JSON file:

```
import calendar
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

year = 2021

for month in range(1, 13):
    r = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
    start = f"{year}-{month:0>2d}-01"
    end = f"{year}-{month:0>2d}-{r[1]}"
    filename = f'data-{year}-{month:0>2d}.json'
    
    url = f"apilink/getKwh?token={token}&clientId={clientId}&siteId={siteId}&from={start}&to={end}"

    response = urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    jsonString = json.dumps(data)
    jsonFile = open("data.json", "w")
    jsonFile.write(jsonString)
    jsonFile.close()

    #print(jsonString)
```

Printing jsonString gives me the below:

```
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-01-01 - 2021-01-31", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 708550.8319999998, "pv_electricity": 191839.79899999997}}]}
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-02-01 - 2021-02-28", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 696012.9289999999, "pv_electricity": 170749.32900000006}}]}
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-03-01 - 2021-03-31", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 760362.3220000002, "pv_electricity": 130641.14300000001}}]}
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-04-01 - 2021-04-30", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 708378.577, "pv_electricity": 106324.401}}]}
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-05-01 - 2021-05-31", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 687580.101, "pv_electricity": 86021.56199999998}}]}
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-06-01 - 2021-06-30", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 698863.9789999999, "pv_electricity": 71402.458}}]}
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-07-01 - 2021-07-31", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 715635.6180000001, "pv_electricity": 80797.80699999999}}]}
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-08-01 - 2021-08-31", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 692463.586, "pv_electricity": 110086.07599999999}}]}
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-09-01 - 2021-09-30", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 20455.919, "pv_electricity": 4785.178}}]}
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-10-01 - 2021-10-31", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 0, "pv_electricity": 0}}]}
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-11-01 - 2021-11-30", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 0, "pv_electricity": 0}}]}
{"data_json": [{"site": "TEST Western Cape DC", "year": 2021, "month": "2021-12-01 - 2021-12-31", "total_kWh": {"grid_electricity": 0, "pv_electricity": 0}}]}
```

However when it export to JSON file it only has the last month, how could I include all of the above months in the JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwriting the same file every time you do `open("data.json", "w")`.

Here's a refactoring of your code that fetches all data into a list first, then writes that list into the file.

```
import calendar
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json


def get_datas(year):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        r = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
        start = f"{year}-{month:0>2d}-01"
        end = f"{year}-{month:0>2d}-{r[1]}"
        url = f"apilink/getKwh?token={token}&clientId={clientId}&siteId={siteId}&from={start}&to={end}"
        response = urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(response.read())
        yield data


datas = list(get_datas(2021))
with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(datas, fp)
```

The other option would be to use the append mode, and write each JSON object on a line of its own, so you'd end up with a [JSONLines/ndjson](https://jsonlines.org/) file.

#### EDIT based on comments

To get multiple years,

```
datas = []
for year in (2020, 2021):
    datas.extend(get_datas(year))
# write to file...
```

Comment: Thanks @AKX this worked, would I be able to add both 2020 and 2021 in one list?

Comment: Thanks @AKX lastly, how would you recommend adding multiple siteIDs to the JSON

Comment: I'd probably structure those as a dict, so you'd have a mapping of site id to date info.

Answer (score -1):

You are overwriting the file. You should use append mode `open("data.json", "a")`.

Please read below link for basic file handling in python.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-handling-python/